# Biggest k values in spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large spark dataset spread across multiple partitions. Following is its schema

| userId | contest id | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | Contest1 | 10 |
| User2 | Contest1 | 15 |
| User3 | Contest2 | 8 |
| User4 | Contest4 | 20 |

The above data is huge and is partitioned evenly. So Contest1 data is distributed across multiple partition. I cant repartition by contestID due to large skew on number of rows for each contest.

I want to create another dataset such that it contains say top 10 users for each contest. I.e For each contest which 10 users scored highest number of points.

How can I process multiple partitions in parallel and sort of do a merge sort for top 10 values received for each partition. I want to avoid sorting and use sort of max heap algorithm here.

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some contests can have a large number of rows, you cannot group by contests, collect the list of (userid, points) tuples and select the 10 largest at the end.

What we can do is define a `topK` UDAF (user defined aggregation function) that would aggregate that top K elements as we go to avoid creating partitions with too many rows.

Let's consider the following dataset:

```
df.show()
+------+---------+------+
|userId|contestId|points|
+------+---------+------+
| User1| Contest1|    10|
| User2| Contest1|    15|
| User3| Contest2|     8|
| User4| Contest4|    20|
| User5| Contest1|    20|
| User6| Contest1|     5|
+------+---------+------+
```

Then, here is the code of the UDAF and its usage:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

case class Elements[T: TypeTag](seq : Seq[T])

class TopKElements[T: TypeTag](val k : Int)(implicit ord : Ordering[T])
                extends Aggregator[T, Elements[T], Elements[T]] {
    override def zero: Elements[T] = Elements(Seq.empty)

    override def reduce(b: Elements[T], a: T): Elements[T] =
        Elements((b.seq :+ a).sorted(ord.reverse).take(k))

    override def merge(b1: Elements[T], b2: Elements[T]): Elements[T] =
        Elements((b1.seq ++ b2.seq).sorted(ord.reverse).take(k))

    override def finish(reduction: Elements[T]): Elements[T] = reduction

    override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Elements[T]] = Encoders.product

    override def outputEncoder: Encoder[Elements[T]] = Encoders.product
}

val topK = udaf(new TopKElements[(Int, String)](3))

df.groupBy("contestid")
  .agg(topK('points, 'userid)("seq") as "top_k")
  .show(false)
```

```
+---------+---------------------------------------+
|contestid|top_k                                  |
+---------+---------------------------------------+
|Contest2 |[{8, User3}]                           |
|Contest1 |[{20, User5}, {15, User2}, {10, User1}]|
|Contest4 |[{20, User4}]                          |
+---------+---------------------------------------+
```